# Concatenate strings from other functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to run the function myFunction in google app script and the result is a concatenated string.The result i want is 'AB' but my return value is only 'A'.

How should I do it

```js
var data = 'A';

function myFunction() {
    appenData(data);
    Logger.log(data);
}

function appenData(data) {
    data += 'B';
}
```

Comment: data is local to appenData (you passed it as parameter)

Comment: [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Answer (score 3):

The parameter you passed to `appenData(data)` is local to the function. If you change your function to:

```
function appenData() {
    data += 'B';
}
```

it should work.